# Silverlight authentication for admin and regular users

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, admin

I have created a new silverlight business application in visual studio.

It auto generates the login section etc, however I want only certain parts of the website to be accessible by certain users.

For instance, I want one user that is an admin, who would have fully access to all the website, and a regular user that would only have access to specific part of the site.

I have used this turorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) which has helped to an extent, but it does not seem to allow me to create access rights to specific users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this. One simple way is to have a "user role" table and a mapping between the user id and the role id.

Then in your navigation check that the the role is allowed to view/edit that part of the site and either allow access or display a "you don't have sufficient privileges" message.

The exact nature of the code required will depend on your navigation implementation.

Comment: I did the mapping and invoked the web service function, works a treat thanks.